# Have issues access to ES with AWS request signing

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, go, amazon-elasticsearch

I am building a golang RESTful API and trying to access ES using signed requests.
I have followed documentation on AWS the documentation of the Golang AWS elastic search client package I am using (olivere/elastic)

Following golang code is used to create a new client

```
signer := v4.NewSigner(credentials.NewStaticCredentials("IAM_USER_ID", "IAM_USER_SECRET", ""))
awsClient, err := aws_signing_client.New(signer, nil, "es", "us-east-1")
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return elastic.NewClient(
    elastic.SetURL("https://my-aws-endpoint.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"),
    elastic.SetScheme("https"),
    elastic.SetHttpClient(awsClient),
    elastic.SetSniff(false), // See note below
)
```

In ElasticSearch AWS console, I have modified an access policy like that:
[image: selected access policy template]
[image: access policy]

Seems I am able to discover the ES node, but when I try to execute a query, ES return http status 403 – don't have permission.

I also have tried to grant IAM user with the AmazonESFullAccess policy but seems it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: hi @eolexe were you able to  resolve this issue. if yes can you add the solution

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an issue in the signing library.
The following pull request fixed it. (not yet merged)
https://github.com/sha1sum/aws_signing_client/pull/3

Answer (score 0):

following code worked for me. es version is 7.10

```
  import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
    
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
        "github.com/olivere/elastic/v7"
    
        aws "github.com/olivere/elastic/v7/aws/v4"
    )
    
    func main() {
        var (
            accessKey = "aws key"
            secretKey = "aws secret key"
            host      = "es url"
            region    = "es region"
        )
    
        creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(accessKey, secretKey, "")
        _, err := creds.Get()
    
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Wrong credentials: ", err)
        }
    
        signingClient := aws.NewV4SigningClient(creds, region)
    
        // Create an Elasticsearch client
        client, err := elastic.NewClient(
            elastic.SetURL(host),
            elastic.SetSniff(false),
            elastic.SetHealthcheck(false),
            elastic.SetHttpClient(signingClient),
        )
    
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    

        indices, err := client.IndexNames()
        fmt.Println(indices)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    
        // Just a status message
        fmt.Println("Connection succeeded")
    }
```